# select group same column by date into different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of logins that looks like this:

```
Created                |  Action
20/01/2016 08:00:00 AM    login
20/01/2016 10:05:10 AM    logout
20/01/2016 12:00:00 PM    login
20/01/2016 04:12:22 PM    logout
21/01/2016 08:00:50 AM    login
21/01/2016 09:44:42 AM    login
21/01/2016 10:44:42 AM    login
21/01/2016 04:00:42 PM    logout
```

I need to select a result set that looks like this:

```
Created        |    Login   |    Logout        
20/01/2016      08:00:00 AM   04:12:22 PM
21/01/2016      08:00:50 PM   04:00:42 PM
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),li.Created,10) [Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(li.Created),8) [Login],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(lo.Created),8) [Logout]
FROM Logins li
LEFT JOIN Logins lo ON lo.[Action] = 'logout'
GROUP BY li.Created
```

But the result is not grouped by date.

What is the proper way?

Comment: Try `group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),li.Created,10)` instead.

Comment: How would you know that 04:12:22AM for some reason comes _after_ 08:00:00AM the same day...? What is the rule that says which time to pick?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It was a typo, I corrected it

Comment: So the 20th should be 4pm too?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes it has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Rahul's answer, but you can do a self join to get first login/last logout and just group by the date to get the result you're asking for;

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,     li.created)  [Date], 
       CONVERT(TIME, MIN(li.created)) [Login],
       CONVERT(TIME, MAX(lo.created)) [Logout] 
FROM Logins li 
JOIN Logins lo 
  ON CONVERT(DATE, li.created) = CONVERT(DATE, lo.created)
 AND li.action = 'login'
 AND lo.action = 'logout' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, li.created)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13f0e/1).

EDIT: untested for SQL Server 2005, you may need to set a length for the varchars;

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, li.created, 110)    [Date], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(li.created), 8) [Login],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(lo.created), 8) [Logout] 
FROM Logins li 
JOIN Logins lo 
  ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, li.created, 110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, lo.created, 110)
 AND li.action = 'login'
 AND lo.action = 'logout' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, li.created, 110)
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2872/2).

Comment: @Smith You tagged with SQL Server 2008 so I tested with that. Maybe you should re-tag the question if you need SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Now I want to join the employee names from the employee table, do i need to ask another question or add it to this one?

Comment: @Smith Better to ask a new one since changing a question that has multiple answers already is usually frowned upon (and you'll get more attention for a new question anyway :) )

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),li.Created,10) [Date], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(li.Created),8) [Login],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(lo.Created),8) [Logout] 
From Logins li 
Left Join Logins lo  on lo.[Action] = 'logout' 
GROUP BY CAST(li.Created AS DATE)
```

ie, you need to group by your records on the date only and not by date and time both.

Comment: I think that'd get login 04:12:22AM logout 10:05.10AM...?

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi i am getting the same logout time for all the results

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that the 4am logout on the 20th in your results is an oversight, otherwise we would need to know the logic that determines that it should be considered the logout time for that day.

One problem is that you're trying to display just dates as your groups, but you're grouping by the date and time.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    CAST(LI.created AS DATE) AS created,
    MIN(CAST(LI.created AS TIME)) AS login,
    MAX(CAST(LO.created AS TIME)) AS logout
FROM
    dbo.My_Table LI
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.My_Table LO ON
    LO.action = 'logout' AND
    CAST(LO.created AS DATE) = CAST(LI.created AS DATE)
WHERE
    LI.action = 'login'
GROUP BY
    CAST(LI.created AS DATE)
```

Another thing to consider is whether or not login periods can span date boundaries. If this is in the tech industry then it wouldn't be odd to have a login of 1/20 10pm and a logout of 1/21 2am. ;)

Comment: I am also getting the same logout time for all the results

Comment: I've added a `JOIN` condition based on the date as well, which I think should correct that issue. No time to test it right now, but hopefully that does the trick.